# How to set end of joint that has fixed transform?

Tags: unity, rigidbody, joints

I'm implementing chains locked the door, and used Hinge joints to linked the chains like this picture:

[image]

As you can see, last chain doesn't have connected body because it is end. And when the game starts, links were broken:

[image]

How to make last chain just hang in the position like first hinge object?

Also, chains are too way swaying, is there a way to reduce it? I increased every chain's mass to 100~1000, but seems nothing changed. Give it too much mass results broken joints.

Any advice will very appreciate it!

Comment: Add a `Rigidbody` to the last part of the chain and set it's property `isKinematic` to `true`.

If that does not work, just set the parent of the last chain element to this switch/lock on the wall like: `lastChainElem.transform.SetParent(wallSwitch.transform);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by freezing the position of last chain, but not rotation. It might also work the way @Spectre suggested.